# C# What does List<List<string>> mean?

Tags: c#

What is `List<List<string>>` and how do I get the data out (as Strings)?

Comment: Means each index of outer List contain a List of strings. As List[0] = List<string>

Comment: Why was this downvoted?  It was helpful to me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
List<List<string>> lists;
...
foreach (List<string> list in lists)
{
    foreach (string s in list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 20):

It's a list of lists of strings. Each element of the "outer" list is a list of strings. The simplest way to "flatten" the list is to use LINQ:

```
var flattened = listOfLists.SelectMany(list => list);

foreach (var value in flattened)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

It is a list of lists of strings.

To get to the actual strings, you need to iterate over the list of lists, then for each list of strings, iterate over it to get the strings.

```
foreach(var stringList in myList)
{
   foreach(var aString in stringList)
   {
      // do someting with aString
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's exactly what it reads it is a List of (List of strings), you can use `SelectMany` to flatten the object to just  `List<string>`

```
List<List<String>> objListOfListString = new List<List<string>>();
//Some code here that fills the above object
List<string> justAListOfString = objListOfListString.SelectMany(s => s).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

It implies **List of List of strings.**

e.g.

```
//Add data in inner list
var lstString = new List<string>();
Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
  .ToList()
  .ForEach(i => lstString.Add(string.Concat("string", i)));

//Add data in outer list
List<List<string>> lstStrings = new List<List<string>>();
Enumerable.Range(1, 5)
  .ToList()
  .ForEach(j => lstStrings.Add(lstString));

//To fetch data (using lambda)
lstStrings.ForEach(i => i.ForEach(j => Console.WriteLine(j)));
```

//To fetch data using Linq

```
(from x in lstStrings
    from y in x
    select y).ToList().ForEach(j => Console.WriteLine(j));
```

Answer (score 1):

**How to get the values**:

```
foreach(List<string> CurrentList in DoubleList)
{
  foreach(string TheString in CurrentList)
  {
    //...
  }
}
```

**What does it mean**: well, it's a little awkward. As others said, it's a list of a list of strings. It behaves much like a double-indexed array (a *matrix*), like `string[i][j]`. However, while an array is pre-fixed, a list is not.

Answer (score 0):

For a `List<List<string>>`, you can do this:

```
// let's assume listOfListOfString = List<List<string>>
foreach(var list in listOfListOfString)
{
    foreach(var string in list)
    {
        // ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
List<string> CountryOne = new List<string> { "City1", "City2", "City3" };

List<string> CountryTwo = new List<string> { "City4", "City5", "City6" };

List<string> CountryThree = new List<string> { "City7", "City8", "City9" };

List<List<string>> countries = new List<List<string>>();

countries.Add(CountryOne);
countries.Add(CountryTwo);
countries.Add(CountryThree);

Console.WriteLine("Few cities from each country");
Console.WriteLine();
foreach (List<string> country in countries)
{
    foreach(string city in country)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(city);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("----------------------");
}
}
}
```