# How to add list of lists of string in PDF with iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have created 2D list of strings:

```
List<List<string>> questions = new List<List<string>>();
```

How can I add elements of this 2D list to my PDF file using iTextSharp?

```
if (pdfFile.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
     Document document = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER, 20, 20, 42, 35);
     PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(pdfFile.FileName, FileMode.Create));
     document.Open();

     Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("Test");

     document.Add(paragraph);

     document.Close();
```

}

I have tried this with simply for loop and command:`document.Add(questions[i]);`
but it is not working.

Comment: Apart from the fact that you need an iTextSharp example and my answer has an iText example, your question is the exact duplicate of [How to create a table based on a two-dimensional array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24404686/i-need-to-create-a-table-and-assign-the-values-into-the-table-in-pdf-using-javaf). You should really read [the documentation](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html) before asking questions as simple as this. This isn't even an iTextSharp question. It's about looping over a 2D array and using those values as data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let's take a look at the answer to the question [C# What does List<List<string>> mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12074066/c-sharp-what-does-listliststring-mean)

The accepted answer shows how you can output the contents of this 2D list:

```
List<List<string>> lists;
...
foreach (List<string> list in lists)
{
    foreach (string s in list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

Now look at the answer to the question [How to create a table based on a two-dimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24404686/how-to-create-a-table-based-on-a-two-dimensional-array)

It explains how to use the data of a `List<List<string>>` to construct a `PdfPTable`:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(numColumns);
foreach (List<string> question in questions) {
    foreach (string field in question) {
        table.AddCell(field);
    }
}
```

Now all you have to do, is to add the `table` to the `Document` instance:

```
document.add(table);
```

**Important:** I don't know the value of `numColumns`. You should replace `numColumns` by the number of `string` values of a `question` object. As you create the `questions` object, you (and only you) know the answer to that question. Actually, you could ask the first element of the `questions` list for its size; that way you don't have to guess. Note that it is assumed that every `question` has the same amount of elements.

**UPDATE:** if you don't want a table, you should wrap the `string` values in paragraphs. For instance:

```
foreach (List<string> question in questions) {
    foreach (string field in question) {
        document.Add(new Paragraph(field));
    }
}
```

Comment: You missunderstood me. I don't want to add a table to my PDF. I just want to add groups of questions by numerical order (one after the another). I want it to look like a test in school.

Comment: In that case, you need to wrap the questions and answer in objects (such as `Paragraph`s). You really should do more effort, but I'll update my answer.

Comment: Sorry. I'm a beginner in C#. Thank you for your effort!