# How to save matrix data to an object that you can query with indexes

Tags: c#, vb.net, matrix

I have data in the following format

```
Henry  |Ford  |34|Yes|Absolutely
Wiliman|Tenner|44|No |Why Not?
```

Each row can have a different count of columns. I want to have all values saved as strings. I want to store the data in a way I can query them later with indexes but have not found the right way yet.

I came up with the idea to use a `List(Of List(of String))` but have not found a [way to query this with indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12074066/c-sharp-what-does-listliststring-mean).

Another way would be to use a dataset and write the data into a datatable but this looks to me like the sledgehammer cracking nuts method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Nkosi mentioned, you can just access items in your list with `listToAccess(i)(j)`.

However, you do want to be careful as finding values in a list is O(n). With a list of lists, finding becomes O(n^2).

If your secondary lists are roughly the same size, I would recommend using an array of arrays (matrix). You would make the secondary size the maximum size of your current secondary list. Although this would waste some space, your find would become O(1).

```
Dim matrix As Double(,) = New Double(firstSize, secondSize) {}
```

Then you can do `matrix(i,j)`

Comment: I agree with your assessment. Thought about suggesting 2d arrays but not enough details about the user's requirements. +1 for you.

Comment: OP did mention that each row can have different count of columns.

Comment: @Nkosi unless there are just a few super long lists and the rest are very short, I still think that this would be better. You just set the second length to be the max length.It sounds like OP will do a lot of finding, and it'll be worth the bit of wasted space.

Comment: Like I said before I agree with your original view. How would one handle a situation where the row column length is unknown?

Comment: @Nkosi You mean if you didn't know what the max row size was before creating it? Then I would probably first create the list(of list) and then convert it once to the array before doing indexing.

Comment: that would make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing this answer: [add a list into another list in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9478673/5233410)

Reading them is like accessing any other list.

To get the first field in the first record

```
return records(0)(0)
```

second field in first record

```
return records(0)(1)
```